# How can I get voice.play to work in a cog file for my bot? discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot that plays a video.

I have already implemented the `join` and `leave` commands for my bot (for voice channels) but I cant seem to get it to play a video. I have tried putting it in my main bot file, and it works perfectly fine, but I want to make it a cog so it is its own category under the help command, and I can't figure it out.

It downloaded the song and everything looks fine, but it just doesn't play the video and showed me an error.

This is my bot's code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=["p"])
    async def play(self,ctx, url: str):
        song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
        try:
            if song_there:
                os.remove("song.mp3")
                print("Removed old song file")
        except PermissionError:
            print("Trying to delete song file, but its being played.")
            await ctx.send("ERROR: Music playing.")
            return
        await ctx.send("Getting everything ready...")

        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'default_search': 'auto',
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            print("Downloading audio now\n")
            ydl.download([url])

        for file in os.listdir("./"):
            if file.endswith(".mp3"):
                name = file
                print(f"Renamed File: {file}\n")
                os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e:print(f'{name} has finished playing'))
        voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
        voice.source.valume = 0.07

        nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)
        await ctx.send(f"Playing: {nname}")
        print("Playing\n")
```

And this is the error it gives me:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, seems voice isn't available in a cog as it isn't passed in so needs to be declared. Try adding `voice = ctx.voice_client` above `voice.play(...)`.